# Submitting form with Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-validate

I have a div set up with a form inside and set to post using ajax and returning the results in the div like so

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#guestList").validate({
        debug: false,
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            // do other stuff for a valid form
            //$('form').attr('id', 'guestList1')
            $.post('brides_Includes/guestlistDisplay1.php', $("#guestList").serialize(), function(data) {
                $('#results').html(data)
                $("form#guestList")[0].reset();
            });
        }
    });
});
```

When the results come back it shows the correct changes and replaces the form. However when I post the form again. The relevent changes take place as they should but it then also refreshes the page and shows the posted info in the address bar

How can I post the form and replace it allowing it to post and call the script again without this happening?

Comment: When the form is replaced, does the submit button get replaced? Maybe adding `return false` to the onclick event will correct it.

Comment: Hi Graham.There is no OnClick event

Comment: When the form is submitted it calls the PHP page which completes its actions and is told to PRINT the new form which is does. The new form has the same name and ID as the old form and I can tell the new form is displaed as I have told it to show the new form name so all on that side is fine. So when the new form is loaded and submitted it should do the same again and use the jquery function without a page refresh. but you can see the page refresh and it displays the posted info in the address bar

Comment: I misread part of your code, it looks like `$("#guestList").validate` needs to be told to look at the new form and or it's elements. Are you using the same `ID`?

Comment: Hi Graham The initial form is called guestlist and the new form is also called gustlist. I have tried giving the new form a different ID but it still does the same. So I changed the new form name and added added extra code to validate the new form name and told it to call a different page to see if that made any difference but the reulst were the same, New code looked like this

Comment: Would not let me post it. So in the same script and under the original code I placed this $("#guestList1").validate({
        debug: false,
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            // do other stuff for a valid form
            //$('form').attr('id', 'guestList1')
            $.post('brides_Includes/guestlistDisplay.php', $("#guestList1").serialize(), function(data) {
                $('#results').html(data)
                $("form#guestList1")[0].reset();
            });
        }
    });
});

Comment: New id is guestlist1 additional validate is gusetlist1 and new page to call is guestlistDisplay

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem with returning forms using ajax is that any JavaScrip code already on the page will not see/take advantage of the new form. The best way to get around this is to pass the JavaScrip and the HTML back using ajax.

Basically you pass the below code back each time you pass a new form back. You'll need to update the `ID`s and links (brides_Includes/guestlistDisplay1.php). You will need to replace your code on the main page with this code as well because this is needed to execute any JavaScrip passed back.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#guestList").validate({
    debug: false,
    submitHandler: function(form) {
      // do other stuff for a valid form
      //$('form').attr('id', 'guestList1')
      $.post('brides_Includes/guestlistDisplay1.php', $("#guestList").serialize(), function(data) {
        $('#results').html(data);

        //This executes the JavaScript passed back by the ajax.
        $("#results").find("script").each(function(i) {
          eval($(this).text());
        });

        $("form#guestList")[0].reset();
      });
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Ah many thanks. I removed the script from the page and called the form into the results div as an include initially which has the script included in it. Then when it is posted it calls the second page which also has the script included. Thereby as you suggested, replacing the script each time and it works great. Many thanks I have spent the past 2 days trying to figure this one on my own and got no where :)